# How do I get my function to modify an array that was passed by reference?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm writing a program that lets users input a series of doubles. The program stores `double`s into a 1D array located in `main()`. I also have a function (`getDoubles()`) that stores the values into the array (that is passed by reference). But even though the function has a pointer pointing to it, it doesn't modify anything and everything in the array remains untouched. How do I get `getDoubles()` to modify the array in `main()`?

main():

```
#define SIZE 5

int main(void){
    double arrDoubles[SIZE] = {0};
    
    // out: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ ){
        printf("%lf ", arrDoubles[i]);
    }
    puts("");
    // let user input doubles
    getDoubles(arrDoubles);

    // out: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000; supposed to be whatever the user inputed as doubles
    for ( int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++ ){
        printf("%lf ", arrDoubles[i]);
    }
    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

getDoubles():

```
void getDoubles( int * doubleArr ){
    double userInput;
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        fputs("Enter a decimal number: ", stdout);
        int SCAN_RETURN = scanf("%lf", &userInput);
        fflush(stdin);
        
        if ( SCAN_RETURN != 1 ){
            puts("Invalid input.");
            getDoubles(doubleArr);
        }
        else{
            *doubleArr = userInput;
            doubleArr++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you initialize `i`s in `main`?

Comment: "...an array (that is passed by reference)." -- You are aware that an array can *only* be passed by reference? ;-)

Comment: @StephenNewell Same result -- I actually made a slight typo in the post, the for loops in main is supposed to read `for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)`. Edited for clarity.

Comment: You probably meant `int SCAN_RETURN = scanf("%lf", &userInput);`

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @WillisHershey I did -- thanks for pointing that out. Edited.

Comment: If I were you I'd make a loop to try the `scanf()` again on failure instead of making the function recursive. In rare cases this can cause your stack to overflow if the user enters too many malformed inputs

Comment: Why are you storing `double`s in an `int[]`?

Comment: you should use a linter and activate compiler warnings, you will get direct feedback

Comment: Fixing the warnings makes the code work for me.  Crank up your compiler's warnings until it complains.

Comment: `-Wall` and `-Wextra` save lives

Comment: @WillisHershey Oh! Great catch. That was the issue. Seems to be working now.